# When I want to use views.py i give 'QuerySet' object has no attribute error

Tags: python, django, view

I want to open course detail with next and previous course but my try doesn't work and I get a 404 error and when I delete try and except I get 'QuerySet' object has no attribute error and says error is from counted_views

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYjgf.png)

views.py:

```
def course_detail(request,id):
    try:
        course = Courses.objects.get(id=id)
        id_list = []
        course = Courses.objects.filter(status = True)
        for cr in course :
            id_list.append(cr.id)
        
        if id_list[0] == id:
            next_course = Courses.objects.get(id=id_list[1])
            previous_course =None

        elif id_list[-1] == id:
            next_course = None
            previous_course = Courses.objects.get(id=id_list[-2])

        else:
            next_course = Courses.objects.get(id=id_list[id_list.index(id)+1])
            previous_course = Courses.objects.get(id=id_list[id_list.index(id)-1])



        course.counted_views += 1
        course.save()
        context = {
            'course': course,
            'next_course': next_course,
            'previous_course': previous_course,
        }
        return render(request,"courses/course-details.html",context=context)
    except:
        return render(request,'courses/404.html')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

app_name = 'course'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',Maincourse,name='courses'),
    path('category/<str:cat>',Maincourse,name='course_cat'),
    path('teacher/<str:teacher>',Maincourse,name='course_teacher'),
    path('search/',Maincourse,name='course_search'),
    path('course_detail/<int:id>',course_detail,name='course_detail'),
]
```

models.py:

```
class Courses(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Trainer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='courses',default='default.jpg')
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    counted_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    counted_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    available_seats = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    schedule = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxt9U.png)

Comment: Please provide the *full* traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared a variable `course` initially that fetches an object but then reassigned it to a queryset which now is no longer an object but a list of objects. You can just edit this line from:

```
course = Courses.objects.filter(status = True)
```

To:

```
courses = Courses.objects.filter(status = True)
id_list = [cr.id for cr in courses]
```

As a side note, by convention, models are named in singular so `Course` instead of `Courses`.

Answer (score 0):

The Django filter() method returns a queryset(a list of matching objects) while the get() method returns a single (matching) object or 404 if not found.

As already mentioned, you first assigned the variable 'course' to a get() method which probably didn't find any matching result - hence the 404 error.

Then you assigned the same variable 'course' to a filter() method, overwriting the first definition.

Because a queryset returns a list of objects or an empty list, you can not call Instance (a singular object in the list) methods on a list of 'Instances'.

A possible solution is to use the filter() method and then use exists() to check if it returned an empty queryset or not. Then you can use first() to get the first item in the queryset or pass in the required filter arguments. See example below.

```
courses = Courses.objects.filter(status = True)
if courses.exists():
   #do something here
   first_course = courses.first()
   # and so on
```

Also, take note of the naming conventions as pointed out already by @Nick